# How do I add a space between my fontawesome icon and <p> element?

Tags: html, font-awesome

I want to add a `<p>` text in the same line as that of my `fontawesome` icon, with a space in between the icon and the text. This is my code below:

```
<i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle">&nbsp;</i><p id="first-info">Only <p style="color: greenyellow;">Admin</p> is allowed full priviledges whereas <p style="color: red;">User</p> is 
        allowed partial priviledges.</p>
```

But the text starts always from the next line. Where have I gone wrong? Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not change the display of a `p` tag, then it will ALWAYS start on a new line

So use spans or display:  inline-block

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-1ycn6IcaQQ40/MKBW2W4Rhis/DbILU74C1vSrLJxCq57o941Ym01SwNsOMqvEBFlcgUa6xLiPY/NS5R+E6ztJQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle">&nbsp;</i><span class="first-info">Only <span style="color: greenyellow;">Admin</span> is allowed full priviledges whereas <p style="color: red;">User</span> is allowed partial priviledges.</span>
```

```css
p.first-info { display: inline-block }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-1ycn6IcaQQ40/MKBW2W4Rhis/DbILU74C1vSrLJxCq57o941Ym01SwNsOMqvEBFlcgUa6xLiPY/NS5R+E6ztJQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle">&nbsp;</i><p class="first-info">Only <span style="color: greenyellow;">Admin</p> is allowed full priviledges whereas <p style="color: red;">User</span> is allowed partial priviledges.</p>
```